# TabBar invert tabs scroll direction

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have the following simple TabBar, the tabs at the top are scrollable, I need to start the tabs list from **Right To Left** instead of Left To Right for RTL users because it looks a bad behavior to start from left for them.

Is this possible somehow with Flutter?

This is the code I tried:

```
body: SafeArea(
          child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () => FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),
              child: DefaultTabController(
                length: 7,
                initialIndex: 0,
                child: Column(
                  children: const [
                    TabBar(
                      isScrollable: true,
                      labelColor: Color(0xFFE41E26),
                      // labelStyle: Colors.blue,
                      indicatorColor: Colors.green,
                      tabs: [
                        Tab(
                          text: 'Title 1',
                        ),
                        Tab(
                          text: 'Title 2',
                        ),
                        Tab(
                          text: 'Title 3',
                        ),
                        Tab(
                          text: 'Title 4',
                        ),
                        Tab(
                          text: 'Title 5',
                        ),
                        Tab(
                          text: 'Title 6',
                        ),
                        Tab(
                          text: 'Title 7',
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: TabBarView(
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            'Tab View 1',
                          ),
                          Text(
                            'Tab View 2',
                          ),
                          Text(
                            'Tab View 3',
                          ),
                          Text(
                            'Tab View 4',
                          ),
                          Text(
                            'Tab View 5',
                          ),
                          Text(
                            'Tab View 6',
                          ),
                          Text(
                            'Tab View 7',
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved after adding the required localization codes:

```
return const MaterialApp(
  title: 'Localizations Sample App',
  localizationsDelegates: [
    AppLocalizations.delegate, // Add this line
    GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
    GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
    GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
  ],
  supportedLocales: [
    Locale('en', ''), // English, no country code
    Locale('ar', ''), // Arabic, no country code
  ],
  home: MyHomePage(),
);
```

More here: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your TabBar with Directionality widget and set textDirection property to TextDirection.rtl

```
 DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: Material(
        elevation: 5,
        color: Get.theme.colorScheme.primaryContainer,
        child: const Directionality(
          textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
          child: TabBar(
            isScrollable: true,
            tabs: [
              Tab(text: "Tab 1"),
              Tab(text: "Tab 2"),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```